# pass username and password to REST API in Angular6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have two API and performing the below steps:

1. Hitting the first API to get ID and token
2. Using the ID,token as username and password to hit the second API along with the request body

I tried already with too many options and all of them seems to be working fine with older versions of angular.

**Problem**
When i make the first api call (ping) it return ID and token. I need to call another api2 passing it as username and password(i gave these Returened values as username/passsword in POSTman) . I tried setting some authorisation header as well but it didn't worked and throws 401

I already went through a lot of examples but those doesn't match angular version

**My-http-interceptor.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs'; 

@Injectable()
export class MyHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor() { }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

console.log("intercepted request ... ");

// Clone the request to add the new header.

const authReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set( 'Authorization', 'Basic dmlld2VyLTFAaXR0aWFtLmNvbTp2aWV3ZXIx')});
console.log("Sending request with new header    now ...");
//  console.log(authReq)
//send the newly created request
return next.handle(authReq)
}
}
```

**App.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MyHttpInterceptor } from './my-http-interceptor'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  HttpClientModule
],
providers: [
{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: MyHttpInterceptor,
  multi: true
}
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

export class AppModule { }

**App.compoent.ts**

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import {RequestOptions, Request, RequestMethod,Http,Headers} from '@angular/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

  public ping() {
    this.http.get('https://Api1.com')
      .subscribe(  
        data => console.log(data));}

   public api2(){
     this.http.get('https://Api2.com')
      .subscribe(  
         data => console.log(data));}
   }



}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button (click)="ping()">Method 1</button>
<button (click)="api2()">Method 2</button>
```

Comment: you get reference  from here..https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-registration-login-example?file=app%2F_guards%2Fauth.guard.ts

Comment: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/02/22/mean-with-angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

Comment: tried it, no luck @Vikas

Comment: So your API is working fine when you tested it with Postman?

Comment: Issue is with your API or front-End code ?It would be helpful if you share what error you get and bit more info about your backend  are you using express.js or Spring-boot?

Comment: @Vikas Yes using Postman api is working fine. I'm not using anything from the backend stack

Comment: the error i'm getting  is core.js:1598 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "OK", url: "https://someurl", ok: false, …}